# How can I make a toggle hide all components on a page so that only a background image in visible in react-native? I

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a camera view which shows the camera view as the background. On that page I have a joystick and some sliders to control exposure and move around the view. How can I make a toggle to disable the joystick and sliders so that the view is unobstructed?

Below is my code. What I need is a toggle which can hide the sliders and joystick which are in this view. So when the toggle is selected it just hides everything and only shows the mjpeg stream and when unselected it shows the sliders and joystick again.

```
import { Layout } from "components/common";
import { Box, Text, Icon, IconButton, VStack, Button } from "native-base";
import React, {
  cloneElement,
  useCallback,
  useLayoutEffect,
  useState,
} from "react";
import * as ScreenOrientation from "expo-screen-orientation";
import { useFocusEffect, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { KorolJoystick, KorolSlider, Stepper } from "components/ui";
import { SettingsModal } from "components/CameraView";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { useAppSelector } from "redux-store/store";
// import socket from "tools/poseCam";

var ip = "10.42.0.1";
let ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${ip}:2100/ws`);
ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log("connection established");
};
const CameraView = () => {
  const nav = useNavigation();
  const [showSettings, setShowSettings] = useState(false);
  const { controlType, step } = useAppSelector((state) => state.cameraSettings);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE);
  }, []);
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      return () => {
        ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync();
      };
    }, [])
  );
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Box flex={1} position="relative">
        <WebView
          originWhitelist={["*"]}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          scalesPageToFit
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
          }}
          containerStyle={{
            flex: 1,
          }}
          source={{
            uri: "http://10.42.0.1:2101/mjpeg",
            // uri: "http://mjpeg.sanford.io/count.mjpeg",
          }}
        />
        <VStack
          position="absolute"
          display="flex"
          width="full"
          flexDirection="row"
          padding="5"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <IconButton
            marginRight="auto"
            icon={<Icon as={Feather} color="primary.500" name="arrow-left" />}
            colorScheme="primary"
            onPress={() => nav.goBack()}
          />
          <Button
            size="md"
            startIcon={<Icon size="xs" as={Feather} name="plus" />}
            backgroundColor="primary.500:alpha.40"
          >
            Add Waypoint
          </Button>
          <IconButton
            icon={<Icon as={Feather} color="primary.500" name="settings" />}
            colorScheme="primary"
            onPress={() => setShowSettings(true)}
          />
        </VStack>

        <VStack position="absolute" bottom="30" left="30" width="56" space={2}>
          <VStack>
            {/* <Text>Focus</Text>
            <KorolSlider /> */}
          </VStack>
          <VStack>
            {/* <Text>Zoom</Text>
            <KorolSlider /> */}
          </VStack>
          <VStack>
            <Text>Slide</Text>
            <KorolSlider
              value={x}
              onChange={(slider) => {
                setX(slider);
                console.log(slider);
              }}
              onDragEnd={() => {
                let message = {
                  from: "FromClient",
                  data: {
                    case: "joystick",
                    joystick: {
                      slider: x,
                    },
                  },
                };
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
              }}
            />
          </VStack>
        </VStack>
        <Box position="absolute" right="30" bottom="30">
          {controlType === "joystick" ? (
            <KorolJoystick
              onMove={(values) => {
                console.log(values);
                let message = {
                  from: "FromClient",
                  data: {
                    case: "joystick",
                    joystick: {
                      angle: values.angle.radian,
                      force: values.force,
                    },
                  },
                };
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
              }}
              onStop={(values) => {
                let message = {
                  from: "FromClient",
                  data: {
                    case: "joystick",
                    joystick: {
                      angle: 0,
                      force: 0,
                    },
                  },
                };

                ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
              }}
            />
          ) : (
            <Stepper
              onPress={(dir) => {
                const vel = 5;
                const tiltVel = 5;
                // if (Math.abs(step)<=1){
                //  vel=1
                // }

                if (dir === "up") {
                  const message = {
                    from: "FromClient",
                    data: {
                      case: "controlCMDRel",
                      moveData: { tilt: [step, vel] },
                    },
                  };
                  console.log(message);

                  ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                }

                if (dir === "down") {
                  const message = {
                    from: "FromClient",
                    data: {
                      case: "controlCMDRel",
                      moveData: { tilt: [-step, vel] },
                    },
                  };

                  ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                }
                if (dir === "left") {
                  const message = {
                    from: "FromClient",
                    data: {
                      case: "controlCMDRel",
                      moveData: { pan: [-step, vel] },
                    },
                  };

                  ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                }
                if (dir === "right") {
                  const message = {
                    from: "FromClient",
                    data: {
                      case: "controlCMDRel",
                      moveData: { pan: [step, vel] },
                    },
                  };

                  ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                }
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Box>
      </Box>
      <SettingsModal
        show={showSettings}
        onClose={() => setShowSettings(false)}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default CameraView;
```

Comment: you should give us some codes (example), so we can understand what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where (on which element) your background image is set,but you can render any component conditionally like this:

```
return(
<div>
  I am wrapper
  {isVisible && <div>I am visible if isVisible is true</div>}
</div>
)
```

and you can set background image on the parent div, so when the child div is not visible you can see the background image.